# Schedule to run a method Daily 8 AM in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, schedule

how Call Method in ASP.NET MVC 
For example, in one method, bring out a list of people who are born and send them a congratulatory message.

Comment: Maybe "Windows Task Scheduler" can work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no code provided but generally, there are several options I could think of:

1. The built-in `BackgroundService`
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

you can create a structure like this in the backgroundservice:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        //Do work

        await Task.Delay(timeSpan, stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

2. `Quartz` task scheduler, which might be overkill for your task.
   https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/
3. A long-running timer (not recommended)
4. Windows Task Scheduler Task on the Server, triggering an API Method.
   (Suggested by [Fildor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982149/fildor))

Comment: 4. Windows Task Scheduler Task on the Server, triggering an API Method.

Comment: yea, but that barely falls under the asp.net service. the scheduling part kinda external to the service.

Comment: So? All you do is trigger a logic. All the code is in the ASP.NET MVC Application. That way you can even change the scheduling without touching the App's code or having to restart or anything.

Comment: sure. but when enlisting the options i was thinking of more convenient internal ways of doing so, is all :)

Comment: That granted. But having used Task Scheduler, to me, that's much more convenient than any of the above listed options (for the reasons in above comment). So feel free to add it to your answer, or don't. Your choice.

Comment: @Fildor fair, i'll add this one as well

Comment: I am using DNTScheduler .with nuget  Install-Package DNTScheduler -Version 1.1.0 thank you.